# JavaScript prototype functions overriding

Tags: javascript

I am using open source [Able Player](https://github.com/ableplayer/ableplayer) from Github
The [UI](https://ableplayer.github.io/ableplayer/demos/video6.html) is very basic and I was wondering the best way to extend the player and override functions like

```
AblePlayer.prototype.getSvgData = function(button) {...
AblePlayer.prototype.setButtonImages = function() {...
```

So that I can use my own icons etc.

without motifying the original `ableplayer.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to extend `AblePlayer` with prototypical inheritance best practices according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```js
(function(){
    const AblePlayer = window.AblePlayer;

    function MyAblePlayer(...args) {
        AblePlayer.call(this, ...args);
    }

    MyAblePlayer.prototype = Object.create(AblePlayer.prototype);
    MyAblePlayer.prototype.constructor = MyAblePlayer;

    /* @override method*/
    MyAblePlayer.prototype.getSvgData = function (...args) {
        // if you need to call super do:
        const superResult = AblePlayer.prototype.getSvgData.call(this, ...args);

        // add your code here

        return superResult; // or return some other result
    }

    // Copy static properties
    Object.assign(MyAblePlayer, AblePlayer)

    // Finally override global reference
    window.AblePlayer = MyAblePlayer;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it out and let u know.